# get index of all objects in a json array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my json::

[{
    "name": "Roy",
    "city": "Dallas",
    "state": "Texas"
}, {
    "name": "Karla",
    "city": "LA",
    "state": "California"
},{
    "name": "Felix",
    "city": "Las Vegas",
    "state": "Nevada"
},{
    "name": "Fred",
    "city": "Miami",
    "state": "Florida"
},{
    "name": "Bill",
    "city": "Atlanta",
    "state": "Georgia"
},{
    "name": "Mike",
    "city": "Chicago",
    "state": "Illinois"
},{
    "name": "Tim",
    "city": "Worcester",
    "state": "MA"
},{
    "name": "Ryan",
    "city": "Austin",
    "state": "Texas"
},{
    "name": "Sam",
    "city": "Boston",
    "state": "MA"
},{
    "name": "Sarah",
    "city": "Houston",
    "state": "Texas"
}]

I want to capture all index numbers with state of Texas:

Please help.

Comment: Can you specify what you're struggling with? JSON parsing? Loop logic? A combination of the two?

Comment: loop logic.I wan't to get all index numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) while collecting indices of matching state.

```js
var array = [{ name: "Roy", city: "Dallas", state: "Texas" }, { name: "Karla", city: "LA", state: "California" }, { name: "Felix", city: "Las Vegas", state: "Nevada" }, { name: "Fred", city: "Miami", state: "Florida" }, { name: "Bill", city: "Atlanta", state: "Georgia" }, { name: "Mike", city: "Chicago", state: "Illinois" }, { name: "Tim", city: "Worcester", state: "MA" }, { name: "Ryan", city: "Austin", state: "Texas" }, { name: "Sam", city: "Boston", state: "MA" }, { name: "Sarah", city: "Houston", state: "Texas" }],
    indices = array.reduce((r, o, i) => (o.state === 'Texas' && r.push(i), r), []);

console.log(indices);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` and `filter()` methods like following.

```js
var data = [{ "name": "Roy", "city": "Dallas", "state": "Texas" }, { "name": "Karla", "city": "LA", "state": "California" },{ "name": "Felix", "city": "Las Vegas", "state": "Nevada" },{ "name": "Fred", "city": "Miami", "state": "Florida" },{ "name": "Bill", "city": "Atlanta", "state": "Georgia" },{ "name": "Mike", "city": "Chicago", "state": "Illinois" },{ "name": "Tim", "city": "Worcester", "state": "MA" },{ "name": "Ryan", "city": "Austin", "state": "Texas" },{ "name": "Sam", "city": "Boston", "state": "MA" },{ "name": "Sarah", "city": "Houston", "state": "Texas" }];

var indexes = data.map(function(item, i){
    if(item.state == "Texas") return i;
}).filter(function(item){ return item!=undefined; });

console.log(indexes);
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need?

```js
var obj=[{ "name": "Roy", "city": "Dallas", "state": "Texas" }, { "name": "Karla", "city": "LA", "state": "California" },{ "name": "Felix", "city": "Las Vegas", "state": "Nevada" },{ "name": "Fred", "city": "Miami", "state": "Florida" },{ "name": "Bill", "city": "Atlanta", "state": "Georgia" },{ "name": "Mike", "city": "Chicago", "state": "Illinois" },{ "name": "Tim", "city": "Worcester", "state": "MA" },{ "name": "Ryan", "city": "Austin", "state": "Texas" },{ "name": "Sam", "city": "Boston", "state": "MA" },{ "name": "Sarah", "city": "Houston", "state": "Texas" }],
indexes=[];

for(var index in obj){
  if(obj[index]['state']=='Texas')
    indexes.push(index);
}

console.log(indexes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the collection and add the indexes in an array, where state is 'Texas'. If you are using server side code, you can Deserialize the response (to a target type that contains same attributes as JSON object) using JSON parser. If you are using Javascript, you can JSON.parse(jsonString) to convert into an object array and then enumerate

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to achieve this. Iterating over a variable, say 'i', would be useful.

```
texas_indecies = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  if (array[i].state == "Texas"){
    texas_indecies.push(i);
  }
}
```